# View with albums listed, plus their corresponding songs

Tags: nodes, views

I feel like I must be missing some fundamental understanding of views or something...

I'm creating a site for a single band. I have two content types, “Album” and “Song.” The “Song” type has a mandatory reference to the “Album” type using Entity Reference. I have a field for the album cover and year of release in “Album” and I have a track number field in “Song.”

I want to create a page (/music) that lists all albums they have (sorted by year released), with the list of all songs (sorted by track number) for each album displayed along with the album title and cover. The album title and cover would be on the left with the songs listed on the right (two columns, basically).

The Daughtry site had it arranged very similarly to what I was looking for a few days ago, but now it only displays one album. Still, imagine this page with multiple albums showing: http://www.daughtryofficial.com/us/music/

I have gotten very close using a view with the appropriate relationship if I grouped by the album title. The main problem was that the album cover would show for each song instead of once per album. I worked around that by hiding the album cover field and rewriting the output for the album title field to include the album cover. This makes it a bit tricky for formatting, though, as now they are both in the same “field” I guess you could say. And if I want to add more fields that would show only once per album, I would just have to keep rewriting the album title field.

I also tried an attachment view, but that asks if you want the attachment before or after the view, so it would list all albums and then below that list all songs for all album. So they weren’t linked, it was just two separate lists.

Is that the best I can do or am I totally missing the “right” way to do this?

I'm new so I can't "post" images, although it did upload them:

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFOK7.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ynq65.png
```

Comment: Hello, did you find any solution on this?